# Issue with Apache Web server version 2.2.17

Tags: apache

We have some static content which we host on apache web server on a Oracle linux 5 Host. Recently, the host's IP address and DNS changed. We did make these changes to the web server's config file. Now, the static content is accessible via the SSL port. But, we are not able to access it via the regular port. Any ideas on what is going on?

Thanks.